# Is there offset scan function in ClamAV? How to use offset?

Tags: clamav

Scanning files takes so much time. My idea is the first day to scan only files up to 20MB. The next day to scan files of 20MB and more. So I have the idea, that I could just skip first 20 MB bytes and pass to clamAV only the data from +20MB offset running it with the --max-filesize= argument. But how to "cut" these first +20MB of the file?

Comment: Look at "man clamscan"

Comment: You are aware that ClamAV is a tool for  scanning Emails to detect Windows viruses, and not a general Linux scanning tool , aren't you? The idea of a "Linux virus" or a Windows Virus running on Linux is absurd. Do run a mail server for a bunch of Windows clients?

Comment: @waltinator: I am not running any server, but I need to check windows files on NTFS partitions and also Firefox profiles on NTFS and server files saved on local disk (data not published).

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution is to create list of files with specification of size like this:

```
find /media/user/disk -size +$((0*1024*1024+2))c -size -$((12*1024*1024))c > $a/1.f
```

And then run clamscan with --file-list parameter.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).